# How to read PDF file outside public folder?

Tags: php, filesystems, storage, laravel-5.8

I have a problem to access pdf file to embed in my blade, when my pdf storage outside of the public folder.

```
storage_path() returning localhost/projectname/public/storage/ 
$path file is=media/filename.pdf
```

The problem is my pdf are on localhost/projectname/storage/app/public/

I tried to access using

```
Storage::get($path)
```

Not Working because returning The absolute path of file.

```
Url($path)
```

Returning Current url

**This is my blade.php to show pdf files**

```
    <div class="scroller" style="height:500px" data-always-visible="1" data-rail-visible="1" data-rail-color="white" data-handle-color="#A44A1B">
                <object data="{{  url('storage/app/public/'.$pdf) }} }}" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
            </div>
```

**Output is**

```
http://localhost/projectname/public/storage/app/public/media/lpsJIhO1EjlHGJgkk3ymBej5O2WTO0J8HS6sPKiO.pdf
```

**Must be**

```
http://localhost/projectname/storage/app/public/media/lpsJIhO1EjlHGJgkk3ymBej5O2WTO0J8HS6sPKiO.pdf
```

Comment: you need to configure filesystems.php in config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in config/filesystems.php

```
   'storage' => [
                'driver' => 'local',
                'root'   => storage_path(''),
            ],
```

and use

```
fopen(storage_path($path), "r");
```

Comment: Wonderful...thanks manu..nice tips..
i was solved with this way..
delete storage folder inside public directory than 
running CLI php artisan storage:link 
to call pdf i using asset() helper...

Comment: Glad to hear that 